# Mariadb (MySQL) On Windows- problem entering non-ASCII characters in a query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, unicode

```
MariaDB: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.8-MariaDB
OS: Windows 7 Pro 64 bit
```

I have my server database and client all set up (I believe) to support utf8 end to end-

```
(**my.cnf**)

#
# Set everything to utf8
#
# (per https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-character-sets-and-collations/)
#
[client]
default_character_set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default_character_set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character_set_server = utf8mb4
collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'


(**Console**)
    chcp
    Active code page: 65001

(**Mysql client**)
show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                         |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                          |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                        |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                          |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I can store and display unicode characters such as the micron (µ) Omega (Ω) and em dash (—) in the database by importing them from csv files.

However, as soon as I started to try out some queries using unicode characters I hit a problem. Basically, entering a "more than 7 bit" unicode character in a quoted string seems to hide the closing quote mark from the mysql client, which then stays stuck in quote mode. Simple example below-

```
MariaDB [uom]> -- Using plain ASCII- this works
MariaDB [uom]> select replace('cm', 'c', 'm');
+-------------------------+
| replace('cm', 'c', 'm') |
+-------------------------+
| mm                      |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [uom]> -- Try using a unicode character in the query, this fails
MariaDB [uom]> select replace('µm', 'µ', 'u');
    '>
    '>
    '> '
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Interestingly, if I run the same query non-interactively it executes, but the output seems to indicate something in the mysql command line path is not using unicode as the unicode characters are converted to "?" on output-

```
mysql -e "select replace('µm', 'µ', 'u');"
+-------------------------+
| replace('?m', '?', 'u') |
+-------------------------+
| um                      |
+-------------------------+
```

I'm clearly missing a piece of the puzzle here. Any ideas much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I'm working on a non-production db, so I was able (I thought) to set everything top to bottom to utf8mb4 and re-import my data. Still seeing oddities-

1. The system is ignoring the setting for character_set_server in my.cnf. Even though I have the line-

   character_set_server = utf8mb4

in my.cnf, the system still reports it is set to "utf8" after restarting the server. If I issue the commmand `set character_set_server='utf8mb4';` interactively in the client, the variable changes value for the session, but this has no affect on the other issues.

2. When I import a "latin1" file (it's actually cp1252, but Mariadb insists on calling this latin1) containing characters above the 7 bit level, i'm seeing double-encoding. E.g:

   select unit, hex( left(unit, 2)) from codelist where id=3;
   +---------+---------------------+
   | unit    | hex( left(unit, 2)) |
   +---------+---------------------+
   | µmol/L  | C2B56D              |
   +---------+---------------------+
   1 row in set (0.001 sec)

The "micro" character, which should be hex B5 is stored as xC2B5 which is a chinese / Hangul character. With the server, client, and connection all set to utf8mb4, and the csv file i'm importing identified as latin1, I can;t see why double-encoding is happening.

The oddities with the myql client program (emitting "?" characters from the command below, even though it's set to run in utf8mb4-

```
mysql -e "select replace('µm', 'µ', 'u');"
+-------------------------+
| replace('?m', '?', 'u') |
+-------------------------+
| um                      |
+-------------------------+

mysql -e "show variables like '%char%';"
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                         |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                        |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                          |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

and choking on typed-in query strings that include characters like the micro sign also continue.

TBH it's looking like either the Mariadb mysql client is not properly implementing the character set settings it's given, or Windows itself is screwing something up in the environment.

I may end up trying the whole thing on linux to try to determine whether it's the Mariadb side or the OS that is causing the problem.

Comment: Search for "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: I was reasonably sure i'd done what is recommended in that post.

Answer (score 0):

When using the cmd prompt, set that window to use the code page `chcp 65001`:

The command "chcp" controls the "code page". chcp 65001 provides utf8, but it needs a special charset installed, too. some code pages.  To set the font in the console window: Right-click on the title of the window → Properties → Font → pick Lucida Console

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tips.html#windows-unicode-support

Comment: I set the code page early on. I was using Consolas as the terminal font, but i've just re-tried with the font set to Lucida Console and there's no change.

That link to the windows-specific info on Unicode support is new though. I'm going to check that out now.

Comment: And you executed `chcp 65001`?

Comment: yep. This was noted in my original posting-

(**Console**)
    chcp
    Active code page: 65001

Comment: I think I am seeing 2 separate problems. Importing the latin1 (cp1252) data from the text file is obviously the main one.

The fact that the console output doesn't display unicode properly when the mysql client is run in "-e" execute mode, but function parameters with a character like "µ" DO work (whereas interactively it doesn't) seems to imply an issue between the mysql client and Windows console input/output.

I tried the options recommended in the linked doc, but that made no difference.

mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -e "select replace('µm', 'µ', 'm')

Comment: Next step is to upgrade Mariadb to the latest stable version (10.3.12), i'm currently on v10.3.8

Comment: Well that made no difference.

I'm running out of ideas here. Next step I might try installing mariadb (or maybe "original" mysql itself) on a linux machine and see if that exhibits the same issues.

Comment: BTW I double-checked the source data file yet again using a new Notepad++ plugin. The source data is semicolon-delimited csv, so the character immediately before the 'µ' in µmol/L was a semicolon, which does not encode as hex C2, so doesn't explain where the mysterious "C2B5" encoding of the 'µ' character when imported into a utf8mb4 column comes from.

Comment: @Incans - The only real way to check things is to get the hex of things.  Hex `B5` is treated as `µ` by cp1250, cp1251, cp1256, cp1257, dec8, geostd8, hebrew, latin1, latin5, latin7, macroman.  For `utf8` or `utf8mb4`, the hex is `C2B5`

Comment: @Incans - and hex `C2B5` becomes the "Mojibake" `Âµ` when interpreted as cp1250, dec8, latin1, or latin5.

Comment: Oh dear. I was being dumb. I had clearly assumed that as cp1252 was a superset of the ISO8859/1 (latin1) / ASCII family, It and Unicode would probably correspond in their charcodes below hex 254.

Comment: So, my input file IS being read correctly. Excellent. All I need to sort out now is why I can't enter Unicode characters interactively in the client, or display them in "direct execute" (mysql -e) mode.

Comment: @Incans - the "cp" and "latin" guys are each 1-byte codes (I think).  English letters are part of the first 128 codes; _one_ other area (western Europe, Cyrillic, Greek, etc) is encoded in the other 128 codes.  UTF-8 covers the entire world, but requiers 1 to 4 bytes.  Europe is all handled in 1 to 2 bytes; Emojis take 3 or 4; etc.  "Unicode" is related to "UTF-8", but not the same.